# Ignore undefined value when concatenating words split by comma?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like ignore the initial value `undefined` of string variable, I'm trying concatenate words separate by comma but the first concatenation is an undefined. I can not use array of string.

Can it ignore undefined value?

**MyComponent.ts**

```html
  addTag(tag: any){
    this.tags = `${this.asunto.etiquetas}, ${tag}`;
    (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("tags")).value = '';
  }
```

**View of my angular component**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the `etiquetas` when available, otherwise an empty string. Since you can write normal Javascript inside that template literal:

```
  addTag(tag: any){
    this.tags = `${this.asunto.etiquetas ? `${this.asunto.etiquetas}, ` : ""} ${tag}`;
    (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("tags")).value = '';
  }
```

A better version would be to just use a variable

```
  addTag(tag: any){
    const etiqueta = this.asunto.etiquetas ? `${this.asunto.etiquetas}, `} : "";
    this.tags = `${etiqueta}${tag}`;
    (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("tags")).value = '';
  }
```

Comment: ternary operator solved my problem, thanks